# Expected number of trials until k more successes than failures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

If I have a coin with uneven probability ***p*** to get heads(wins), what is the expected number of throws until I get ***k*** more heads than tails? I stop on the throw that I get ***k*** more heads in total.

If p<=0.5 can it be ever *expected* to get more ***k*** heads(wins) than losses in ***n*** throws?

I'm interested in the formula in terms of ***p*** and ***k*** to calculate the expected number of throws  for this problem and how it was derived.

Comment: Please edit in what you have tried and where you are stuck. This is a requirement on this forum.

Comment: @trueblueanil I didn't knew that was a requirement. My probabilities knowledge stops at high school level. Anything more complicated like this and I don't even know how to start.  Conditional probabilities are also above my grade. I just know about stuff but not how to apply them. I haven't tried anything for this problem as I don't know how to try and why to apply certain formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical **generalized random walk** problem as referred to as in some textbook. Define a random variable $c_m$, where $c_m=1$ if the $m$-th throw yields a head, or $c_m=-1$ otherwise. Then the the summation defined as $x(n)=\sum_{m=1}^n c_m$ gives **the number of heads more than tails** on the $n$-th throw (where $n\ge m$). It can be shown, as well as verified by simulation, that for a given value of $k>0$, the expectation of $n$ for $x(n)=k$ is

$E[n]=k/(2p-1)$.

This means that

(1) for $p=1$, $E[n]=k$;

(2) for $p=0.5$, $E[n]=\infty$;

(3) for $p<0.5$, $E[n] < 0$, indicating that it is impossible to get $x(n)=k$.

Comment: For $p<0.5$, there is at least one event k consecutive heads makes contribution. the expected value should be >= k * p^k

Comment: @maplemaple  I am trying to understand your meaning exactly. For example, for $k=1$, do you mean the expectation of $n$ for $x(n)=1$ is $E[n]\geq p$ for $p<0.5$ ? Thanks.